# Bluetooth: read a user provided value and then obtain time from an Android phone

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, android

I'm new to Arduino and try to accomplish following 2 things (via Bluetooth module connected to an Android phone):

1. read an integer value provided by user.
2. obtain current time from the phone (the Arduino board itself has no clock module).

As for #1 - I'm able to print to the Bluetooth terminal as follows: `Serial.println("Enter time to wait(in miliseconds): ");`. I see this string on my phone. However I can't manage to read the value from the terminal using `timeToWait = Serial.read();`. I tried many possible combinations, but in the best case I get it in form of chars' ASCII values. So how can I properly read an integer value from the Bluetooth terminal?

As for #2 - is it possible at all, and if yes - how? If it is not possible to obtain current time via BT from Android phone - is it possible to obtain it via BT from a Linux laptop? How?

Answer (score -1):

Over a serial port, you are transmitting data byte by byte. If you want to interpret them as numbers, you have to parse the data and assemble the numbers yourself.

You could resort to BLE instead, there you may transmit strings and numbers.

Comment: could you, please, create a link with "BLE" pointing on what it is? (Docs maybe)... For me and future readers. Thank you!

Comment: BLE stands for Bluetooth Low Energy, also known as Bluetooth 4.0. 
Official tutorials to be found at e.g. [link] (https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/short-range-guides/b/bluetooth-low-energy/posts/ble-characteristics-a-beginners-tutorial).
An easy/easier approach would be studying the examples for ESP32 in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: I have found this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadASCIIString which looks promising.

Comment: and also https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial.StringToIntExample